# How to enable plugin ccess for sandboxed App in macOS?

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview, skype, appstore-sandbox

I am loading skype web in my WKWebView but skype calling is not happening due to plugin access restriction in sand box app. What is the proper way to provide access for the skype plugin. Any leads are appreciated.

I have tried with these keys in sand boxing:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events:before:10.12</key>
    <string>com.skype.plugin</string>
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a temporary exception to your plist file.

```
Key: com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events
Value: Skype plugin identifier
```

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html

Edit: depending on how the plugin is addressed you might need to change "apple-events". See Technote for more info.

Comment: I already tried with the following keys: **<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
 <string>com.skype.plugin</string>**                                                           and
 **<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
 <array>
  <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/</string>
 </array>**

Comment: You can still ask the user for access once and save the path in a security scoped bookmark for later use.